# getHistoryForKey() Hyperledger fabric get transactions from Buffer nodejs

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to get the transactions and modifications for a value in nodejs with the method  getHistoryForKey(), but when I try to look into the chaincode response
this is the data returned:

```
{ type: 'Buffer',
  data: [ 91, 111, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 32, 79, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 93 ] }
```

But I have no access to the transaction details.

This is the code that I'm using to get the transaction details from the chaincode

```
    const result = await contract.evaluateTransaction('getHistory', req.params.id.toString());
    let resultStr=JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(JSON.parse(resultStr));
    console.log(JSON.parse(resultStr).data.toString());
```

Do you know how to access to the data?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found a solution, the problem was that the object returned should be iterated before returned the Buffer

This code works for me.

```
 let iterator = await ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(id);
    let result = [];
    let res = await iterator.next();
    while (!res.done) {
      if (res.value) {
        console.info(`found state update with value: ${res.value.value.toString('utf8')}`);
        const obj = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
        result.push(obj);
      }
      res = await iterator.next();
    }
    await iterator.close();
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

`result` will be a Buffer object. You can convert it to a javascript string using `.toString()`, ie `result.toString()`. As the transaction you called defines the result returned you will need to understand what the transaction is returning, for example it may be a JSON string so to convert it to a Javascript object you would use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: This was my first try, but when I convert  result.toString() it returns:  [object Object]. And when try to converto to JSON with JSON.parse(resultStr) returns an error:  Failed to evaluate transaction: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.   The problem is that the returned Buffer has two Objects

Comment: Is your chaincode sending the string `[object Object]` back maybe ?